# What does a fuselage frame structure of a non-pressurized transport aircraft look like?

Tags: transport-category

What does a fuselage structure of a non-pressurized transport aircraft look like? I can find loads of examples for pressurized fuselages, but almost nothing for non-pressurized ones. The DHC-5 Buffalo comes to mind, but I can't tell how the fuselage frame is made, e.g.- how the I-beams in the floor are laid out, etc.

Comment: Search "cutaway" to find [images similar to this](http://www.ii.uib.no/~joakim/flightsim/design/3dview/dhc5big.jpg).

Comment: Unpressurised structures are very different from each other, because they are optimised for different features and the restrictions  due to pressurisation are not there.

Answer (score 1):

A pressurized aircraft structure differs from non-pressurised in that the fuselage center area, including the cabin and baggage compartments, are built as a pressure vessel.

Except for:

- strengthened frame and windows
- forward and aft pressure bulkheads
- pressurization systems

the aircraft structure and design not related to the pressure vessel (like the floor) remain unchanged.

There are many examples of non-transport civil aircraft that have pressurised and non-pressurized versions.  For example, a Beechcraft "P-Baron" or a Cessna P210 Pressurized Centurion has smaller windows and different cabin doors you can easily observe.  Yet, the design principles of the aircraft structure, besides beefing up the pressurized areas remain the same.

Most non-pressurized transport aircraft are utility or military in nature, as is the DeHavilland aircraft you mentioned.  Design considerations for these aircraft, like the floor you mentioned, are related to their mission, not pressurization.  That is, unless the floor itself is a pressure vessel wall.

Comment: The biggest difference is in the cross section. Pressurization leads to a round cross section which is less practical and harder to build than a boxy cross section. Also, pressurization means stressed-skin while non-pressurized structures can be a canvas-covered steel tube frame.